# Are the normalizations of $k[X,Y] / (Y^3 - X^5)$ and $k[X,Y] / (Y^5 - X^{19})$ just $k[y/x]$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

In Reid's Undergraduate Commutative Algebra he shows that the normalization of $A = k[X,Y]/(Y^2 - X^3)$ is $k[t]$, where $t = y/x$, because the field of fractions of $A$ is $k(t)$, $t \in k(t)$ is integral over $A$ because $x = t^2$, but is not in $A$ itself, and $k[t]$ is a UFD and therefore normal.

In the chapter exercises, Reid asks for the calculation of the normalizations of $k[X,Y] / (Y^3 - X^5)$ and $k[X,Y] / (Y^5 - X^{19})$. I would guess they must be different than the earlier example, but I don't see how: isn't the field of fractions over each also $k(t)$, where $t = y/x$? And then $t^3 = x^2$ in the first and $t^5 = x^{14}$ in the second, so $t$ is integral over both rings, and again $k[t]$ is a UFD and therefore normal. Do both of these have the same normalization as the first example? If they do, am I right in saying that that's because both the curves $y^5 = x^3$ and $y^5 = x^{19}$ can also be parameterized into a curve over $t$ with no singularities?

Comment: You are wrong. In the first case the normalization is $k[x^2/y]$, while in the second case it is $k[x^4/y]$.

Comment: Maybe it's helpful to consider these rings as isomorphic to $k[t^u,t^v]$ with $u=2$, $v=3$ in the first example, and so on. Now it's easily seen that when $\gcd(u,v)=1$ the field of fractions is $k(t)$, and $t$ is integral.

Comment: I think I get it. So for another example, the normalization of $k[X,Y]/(Y^7 - X^{34})$ would be $k[x^5/y]$?

Comment: Right. ${}{}{}$